# Back button on Navigation Bar glitch / bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have 4 total view controllers in my app, VC #1 has a navigation controller embedded, so everything is done automatically. For some strange reason, I am getting this glitch occasionally that makes my back button not work at all and behave strange this happens when I rotate my device to landscape, come back to portrait and try to go back. Again, this only happens occasionally so I am not sure what could be causing this issue, do you have a suggestion on what I can look into to try to resolve this bug?

See bug in action [HERE](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=33vj61k%3E&s=5#.UogfHpHmqhM)

Longer video of bug in action [HERE](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2yyxxua%3E&s=5#.Uogg45HmqhM)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard, **you have set 2 times the transition**.
It's probably that **you have set a segue** from a button in the parentViewController which show  this controller, **but you have also write the code "[vc pushViewController:...]"**.
This generate the bug (personal experience :D).
**You have to set obviously 1 of these 2 option.**

Let me know!